# Generating multiple results with a single button?

Tags: javascript, function, button

I've written a function to generate an outcome based on percentage when a button is clicked, the issue is that I need that function to repeat 10 Times hence the name of the button. So far

```
roll10.onclick = function generate() {

    var outcome = "";
    var percent = r();

    if (percent >= 0 && percent < 1) {
        outcome = "Outcome 1";
    } else if (percent >= 1 && percent < 10) {
        outcome = "Outcome 2";
    } else if (percent >= 10 && percent < 30) {
        outcome = "Outcome 3";
    } else {
        outcome = "Outcome 4";
    } 


    $("#results").append("<div class='result'>" + outcome);
  
}
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about `for` loops.

Comment: Expanding on above, see: [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments below the question are right. You should learn for loops.

It's as that easy:

```
roll10.onclick = function generate() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var outcome = "";
        var percent = r();

        if (percent >= 0 && percent < 1) {
            outcome = "Outcome 1";
        } else if (percent >= 1 && percent < 10) {
            outcome = "Outcome 2";
        } else if (percent >= 10 && percent < 30) {
            outcome = "Outcome 3";
        } else {
            outcome = "Outcome 4";
        } 


        $("#results").append("<div class='result'>" + outcome);
    }
}
```